# Removendo ponto de interrogação desnecessário de uma String

Tags: python, regex

Tenho possíveis strings, onde gostaria de ter uma maneira de impedir pontos de interrogação desnecessários e adicionar caso falte. Porém essa função se aplica apenas no final da string. Segue a lista abaixo e o resultado esperado:

**Possíveis strings erradas:**

- Como faz para ir ao banheiro????
- Posso investir hoje? Quanto é o valor mínimo
- Não posso fazer isso? Porque????

**Resultado esperado/correto:**

- Como faz para ir ao banheiro?
- Posso investir hoje? Quanto é o valor mínimo?
- Não posso fazer isso? Porque?

Iniciei o código e já verifico se existe ponto de interrogação no final da string e adiciono caso não exista. No caso verifico os últimos 3 caracteres para prevenir casos como: *Eu estou vivo?!*

```
if "?" not in title[-3:]:
        title += "?"
```

Comment: Eu já verifico se nos ultimos 3 caracteres possui algum ponto de interrogação, se não eu adiciono no final da string. Agora, o resto ainda não.

Comment: Aliás, sempre serão perguntas? Por exemplo: "Não posso fazer isso hoje??? Ok." não é uma entrada válida neste caso?

Comment: Sempre serão perguntas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pode usar [regex](/questions/tagged/regex) assim:

```
import re

print(re.sub('\\?+', '?', "Olá????"))
```

O `\?+` busca os pontos de interrogação em sequencia e troca por `'?'`

> **Nota:** O `\\` na frente do `?` serve para escapar o `?` na regex

Você pode querer adaptar para múltiplos tipos de pontos, como:

```
import re

def remove_pontuacao_em_sequencia(str):
    return re.sub('([?!.,])+', '\\1', str)

print( remove_pontuacao_em_sequencia('Olá???') )
print( remove_pontuacao_em_sequencia('Olá!!!') )
print( remove_pontuacao_em_sequencia('Olá...') )
print( remove_pontuacao_em_sequencia('Olá,,,') )
```

Comment: Valeu cara, ajudou aqui. Adicionei sua resposta no meu caso. Abraços

Comment: E ai, o sr. downvoter poderia explicar o downvote? Quero saber aonde posso melhorar da resposta ou se a resposta foi em hora inconveniente. Não se preocupe sr. downvoter, eu não sou do tipo que guarda rancor, não vou lhe devolver downvotes, eu não dou nem downvote para quem já me atacou e xingou no site, muito menos por alguém discordar de minhas respostas, então pode se manifestar a vontade.

Comment: o sr. downvoter não se manifestou até hoje... nem os 3 downvoters da minha pergunta :/ Mas voltei pra avisar que em 2018 isso resolveu e passei a usar regex sempre pra tudo kkkk abraços

Answer (score 0):

Para adicionar também ao final da *string* que não possui o ponto de interrogação, você pode utilizar a expressão regular:

```
(\?+|$)
```

Que basicamente captura qualquer sequência de um ou mais pontos de interrogação ou o final da linha, podendo, assim, substituir pelo ponto de interrogação único.

```
import re

tests = [
    ('Como faz para ir ao banheiro????', 'Como faz para ir ao banheiro?'),
    ('Posso investir hoje? Quanto é o valor mínimo', 'Posso investir hoje? Quanto é o valor mínimo?'),
    ('Não posso fazer isso? Por que????', 'Não posso fazer isso? Por que?')
]

for test in tests:
    result = re.sub(r'(\?+|$)', '?', test[0])
    assert result == test[1]
```

Se, por acaso, sua *string* terminar em uma pontuação que não seja um ponto de interrogação, ficará um tanto quanto estranho o resultado:

```
print(re.sub(r'(\?+|$)', '?', 'teste!'))  # teste!?
```

Se for interessante eliminar esta pontuação final, basta adicionar junto ao `$` na expressão regular:

```
(\\?+|[{string.punctuation}]+$)
```

Onde `string.punctuation` refere-se ao módulo [`string`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/string.html#string.punctuation). Neste caso, a entrada `teste!!!,..;!` viraria `teste?`.

```
import re
import string

tests = [
    ('Como faz para ir ao banheiro????', 'Como faz para ir ao banheiro?'),
    ('Posso investir hoje? Quanto é o valor mínimo!..,,', 'Posso investir hoje? Quanto é o valor mínimo?'),
    ('Não posso fazer isso? Por que????', 'Não posso fazer isso? Por que?'),
    ('teste!!!,..;!', 'teste?')
]

for test in tests:
    result = re.sub(f'(\\?+|[{string.punctuation}]+$)', '?', test[0])
    assert result == test[1]
```